# Command line using ng causes error, nx corrects error

Tags: nrwl-nx, nrwl, nomachine-nx

I am getting the following on attempting to create a domain

```
Executing task: ng generate @srleecode/domain:libraries --application=medsoft --domain=app-load --libraries=data-access --prefix=mds --buildable --enableIvy --strict --no-interactive --dry-run <
```

An unhandled exception occurred: Package "@srleecode/domain" was found but does not support schematics.
See "/tmp/ng-kaGB1T/angular-errors.log" for further details.
The terminal process "/usr/bin/bash '-l', '-c', '/home/stclair/__/@q/zim/node_modules/.bin/ng generate @srleecode/domain:libraries --application=medsoft --domain=app-load --libraries=data-access --prefix=mds --buildable --enableIvy --strict --no-interactive --dry-run', 'ng generate @srleecode/domain:libraries --application=medsoft --domain=app-load --libraries=data-access --prefix=mds --buildable --enableIvy --strict --no-interactive --dry-run'" terminated with exit code: 127.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

/tmp/ng-kaGB1T/angular-errors.log

```
[error] Error: Package "@srleecode/domain" was found but does not support schematics.
```

at SchematicEngineHost.resolve (/home/stclair/**/@q/zim/node_modules/.pnpm/@angular-devkit+schematics@12.2.0/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/node-module-engine-host.js:53:23)
at SchematicEngineHost._resolveCollectionPath (/home/stclair/**/@q/zim/node_modules/.pnpm/@angular-devkit+schematics@12.2.0/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/node-module-engine-host.js:80:37)
at SchematicEngineHost.createCollectionDescription (/home/stclair/**/@q/zim/node_modules/.pnpm/@angular-devkit+schematics@12.2.0/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/file-system-engine-host-base.js:118:27)
at SchematicEngine._createCollectionDescription (/home/stclair/**/@q/zim/node_modules/.pnpm/@angular-devkit+schematics@12.2.0/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/engine.js:162:40)
at SchematicEngine.createCollection (/home/stclair/**/@q/zim/node_modules/.pnpm/@angular-devkit+schematics@12.2.0/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/engine.js:155:43)
at GenerateCommand.getCollection (/home/stclair/**/@q/zim/node_modules/.pnpm/@angular+cli@12.2.0/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/schematic-command.js:143:35)
at GenerateCommand.initialize (/home/stclair/**/@q/zim/node_modules/.pnpm/@angular+cli@12.2.0/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/schematic-command.js:62:37)
at async GenerateCommand.initialize (/home/stclair/**/@q/zim/node_modules/.pnpm/@angular+cli@12.2.0/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/generate-impl.js:20:9)
at async GenerateCommand.validateAndRun (/home/stclair/**/@q/zim/node_modules/.pnpm/@angular+cli@12.2.0/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command.js:121:22)
at async Object.runCommand (/home/stclair/**/@q/zim/node_modules/.pnpm/@angular+cli@12.2.0/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js:224:24)

I am using the following:

"@angular/core": "^12.2.0",
"@srleecode/domain": "^12.6.2",
Linux Mint 20.2

Version: 1.58.2
Commit: c3f126316369cd610563c75b1b1725e0679adfb3
Date: 2021-07-14T22:30:16.440Z
Electron: 12.0.13
Chrome: 89.0.4389.128
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 8.9.255.25-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.4.0-80-generic
"@nrwl/angular": "^12.6.5",
"@nrwl/cli": "12.6.5",
"@nrwl/cypress": "12.6.5",
"@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "12.6.5",
"@nrwl/jest": "12.6.5",
"@nrwl/linter": "12.6.5",
"@nrwl/storybook": "^12.6.5",
"@nrwl/tao": "12.6.5",
"@nrwl/workspace": "12.6.5",

When I try:

```
stclair@msi-home:~/__/@q/zim$ pnpx nx generate @srleecode/domain:libraries --application=medsoft --domain=app-load --libraries=data-access --prefix=mds --buildable --enableIvy --strict --no-interactive --dry-run
```

the code is generated as expected.

Is there a way for me to force bash to use nx instead of ng?